# Set event after select option in combobox. Kendo UI, ASP.ENT

Tags: javascript, asp.net, kendo-ui

```
@Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
.Name("LayoutCombobox")
.DataTextField("Text")
.DataValueField("Value")
.Value(@ViewBag.ListTitle)
.BindTo((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Layouts)
.Events(e => e
    .Change("onComboBoxChange") // Attach the change event handler
)
```

I use this code but not working. I want to set an event to call a javascript method after an option is selected.